# Generate tree hierarchy using nodes and links json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I want javascript function that convert nodes and links json to tree json.

Here is Nodes and Links JSON :

```
    {
      "nodes": [
         {name: "Top Level", group: 1},
         {name: "Level 2: A", group: 1},
         {name: "Son of A", group: 1},
         {name: "Daughter of A", group: 1},
         {name: "Level 2: B", group: 1}
      ],
      "links": [
         {source: 0, target: 1, value: 1},
         {source: 0, target: 4, value: 1},
         {source: 1, target: 2, value: 1},
         {source: 1, target: 3, value: 1}
      ]
   }
```

Here links array which have "source" and "target" is nodes array index.
For e.g {**source: 0**, **target: 1**, value: 1} :- **source:0** means nodes[0] and **target:1** means nodes[1]

After converting above json then Tree hierarchy look like below :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: how do you know who is child of whom & who is parent of whom?

Comment: I bet OP is gonna say *"by the value of `name`"*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @brk 

I have update my question please check it. If any query then let me know. Thanks.

Comment: you could kindly add your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a tree by iterating all `nodes` and generate an object with indices as key and just the name, then by iterating all `links` and append the nodes with parents and children, where a tree structure is generated.

Then you need to flag the children in an object, where it returns later only non children nodes.

```js
var data = { nodes: [{ name: "Top Level", group: 1 }, { name: "Level 2: A", group: 1 }, { name: "Son of A", group: 1 }, { name: "Daughter of A", group: 1 }, { name: "Level 2: B", group: 1 }], links: [{ source: 0, target: 1, value: 1 }, { source: 0, target: 4, value: 1 }, { source: 1, target: 2, value: 1 }, { source: 1, target: 3, value: 1 }] },
    tree = function (object) {
        var o = {}, children = {};

        object.nodes.forEach(function (a, i) {
            o[i] = { name: a.name };
        });

        object.links.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a.target].parent = o[a.source].name;
            o[a.source].children = o[a.source].children || [];
            o[a.source].children.push(o[a.target]);
            children[a.target] = true;
        });

        return Object.keys(o).filter(function (k) {
            return !children[k];
        }).map(function (k) {
            return o[k];
        });
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be as follows:

```
var data; // parse the JSON into here
var buildNode = function(index) {

    var children = data.links.filter(function(x) {
        return x.source === index;
    }).map(function(x) {
        return buildNode(x.target);
    });

    //with ES6 you can use .find to get the first matching item, instead of .filter and [0]
    var parent = data.links.filter(function(x) {
        return x.target === index;
    })[0];
    var parentName = parent ? parent.name : undefined;

    return {
        name: data.nodes[index].name,
        parent: parentName,
        children: children
    };
};

var tree = buildNode(0);
```

---

NB. It might be more efficient to generate an array with the corresponding targets and parents first, instead of iterating through the entire array each time:

```
var data; // parse the JSON into here
var nodeTargets = [];
var nodeParents = [];
data.links.forEach(function(x) {
    if (!nodeTargets[x.source]) {
        nodeTargets[x.source] = []
    }
    nodeTargets[x.source].push(x.target);

    nodeParents[x.target] = x.source;
});
```

This will result in the following array structure in `nodeTargets`:

```
[
    [1, 4],
    [2, 3]
]
```

and the following in `nodeParents`:

```
{
    1: 0,
    4: 0,
    2: 1,
    3: 1
}
```

Then the `buildNode` function would look like this:

```
var buildNode = function(index) {

    var children = nodeTargets[index].map(function(x) {
        return buildNode(x);
    });

    var parentIndex = nodeParents[index];
    var parentName;
    if (parentIndex !== undefined) {
        parentName = data.nodes[parentIndex].name;
    }

    return {
        name: data.nodes[index].name,
        parent: parentName,
        children: children
    };
};
```